# How do i read just a single whitespace only from stdin/cin in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble translating the following piece of Java code into its C++ equivalent, meant to be a simple routine to parse an input stream:

```
   String word = br.readLine();
```

Given a sample input file, with the contents displayed in hex by piping through `od -bc`, the following is obtained:

```
   ...
   0000020   040 012 ...
                 \n  
   ...
```

indicating that I've made the input file correctly, by supplying on this one line a space character, following a newline character.

Java is able to read in the entire string a  `'<space>\n'`, but the C++ functions like fgets(), sscanf(), getchar()..., and their equivalent family of functions, all fail to detect this space rather than ignoring it, so instead i'm returned a zero-length string.

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

My g++ compiler details:

> Target: i686-apple-darwin11
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

Code + Sample input (mirrored @ https://gist.github.com/1933400)

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

#define REP(i, a, b)    for(int i=int(a); i<int(b); ++i)

const int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 22;
char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
string sz_word;
int N, M;

int main()
{
    scanf("%d %d\n", &N, &M);
    REP(i,0,N)
    {
        memset(word, 0, MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
        scanf("%s\n", word);
        //if (i == N-1)
        //  cout << word << endl;
    }

    REP(i,0,M)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, sz_word);
        cout << "word: '"  << sz_word << "'" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
1 1
1
<space>
```

Comment: Those are not "in hex", that's octal. 012 == 10 == 0x0a == '\n' (in Linux).

Comment: Those are really C functions rather than C++. Doesn't getline() do what you want? http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ Although this throws away the '\n'.

Comment: None of the functions you list behave the way you describe. The solution to your mystery lies elsewhere in your program. Please produce the smallest complete program that demonstrates your problem, and paste that program into your question. http://sscce.org

Comment: ok, working on producing my canonical program now...

Comment: Previous C++ code @ `http://pastebin.com/eU1mQ08A` / input file @ `http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?5d47fn4e41t6xom`

Comment: Minified code @ `https://gist.github.com/1933400`, together with sample input.

Comment: how do I mark this question as "resolved"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may simplify your program and restate your question:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char word[22];
std::string sz_word;

int main()
{
    std::scanf("%s\n", word);
    std::cout << "'" << word << "'" << std::endl;

    std::getline(std::cin, sz_word);
    std::cout << "word: '"  << sz_word << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

An appropriate input is this:

```
11
 22
```

Note the space at the beginning of the 2nd line. The expected output is:

```
'11'
word: ' 22'
```

The observed output is:

```
'11'
word: '22'
```

Now then, why is the expected output different from the observed output?

Answer: Because you called `scanf`. From the Linux man page:

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives ...A directive is one of the following ...
>   A  sequence  of  white-space  characters  (space,  tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any  amount of white space, including none, in the input.

So, the `\n` in your `scanf` format string matches `any amount of white space`, including the initial white space on the subsequent line.

Comment: TO avoid '\n' matching white space in general use `%[\n]` This will match only a sequence of \n. Alternatively you can use `%[^\n]` to match a line followed by '%c' to match the '\n'. `scanf("%[^\n], dst);scanf("%*c");`

Answer (score 4):

The C++ equivalent is (assuming `br` is some kind of `std::istream`):

```
std::string word;
std::getline(br, word);
```

If you're reading from standard input:

```
std::getline(std::cin, word);
```

The functions you list are all C functions; they're available in C++ if you really want them, but the C++ library is usually more convenient.

UPDATE: having seen your real code, the problem is that you're mixing C and C++ style input; this is usually a bad idea, and requires some care to get it right if you really have to. The problems are:

- `\n` on the end of the `scanf` strings will match any amount of whitespace; it will keep matching any newlines until you enter something other than whitespace. Just remove the `\n`.
- After the last `scanf`, there is still an unmatched `\n` in the input stream, so the first `getline` will give an empty line. You can call `std::cin.ignore()` to skip that newline.

The best solution would be to use `std::cin` for all input, and not try to use the `<cstdio>` functions at all. You can read numbers using the formatted extraction operator: `std::cin >> N >> M;`

Comment: code for `br`: `static final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Comment: @evandrix: I've updated the answer, assuming that's some fancy way of saying the standard input. `std::cin` does all the buffering you're likely to need.

Comment: The `br` is an object in the Java code which I'm trying to convert to  C++

Comment: @evandrix: Well, `System.in` is the standard input, which is `std::cin` in C++. `InputStreamReader` gives it a particular Java interface, which is irrelevant in C++; `BufferedReader` adds buffering, which the C++ object already has. So just use `std::cin`.

Comment: @evandrix: Now I've seen your code, the problem is mixing C and C++ input, which is tricky to get right. See the updated answer.

Comment: Mixing `<cstdio>` and `<iostream>` is a red herring. If OP had used `fgets` instead of `getline`, he would have the same problem. Real problem is `scanf` treats `\n` as any number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` really should work, it's not [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) as "eating" white space, it even includes the line feed in the returned string.

Answer (score 1):

Well something that could help solve your problem with the reading in whitespace.

```
char space[1];
// then set the character to either a NULL or to a basic ' ' <space>
```

SO. for example with your code instead of calling the `scanf()` I would instead make a constructor or just a `setSpace()` type function. Strings can be really messy so I would also get rid of those if at all possible.

Hope this maybe at least inspires some thought somewhere...